# self in python decorators

Tags: python, decorator, self

I want a decorator that would add the decorated function to list, like this :

```
class My_Class(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.list=[]

    @decorator
    def my_function(self)
       print 'Hi'
```

I expect my_function to be added to self.list, but I just can't write this decorator. If I try to write it inside My_Class, then I would have to use @self.decorator, and self does not exist since we're outside any function. And if I try to write it out of My_Class, then I can't retrieve self from my_function.

I know quite similar questions exist, but they are overly complicated, and I'm just learning python and decorators.

Comment: By the way it's not that good to use `list` as a variable name (because this shades the inbuild `list` class).

Comment: Do you want a list of functions that were decorated (each function appearing once), or a list of when functions were called (each function possibly appearing multiple times)?

Comment: @ ovgolovin you're right about this `list` name, what I wrote above was pseudo-code. @interjay I want the list to be instance-specific, and to have each decorated function once.

Comment: @CGGJE: If the list contains each decorated function once, then surely it will be the same for all instances. So why do you want it to be instance-specific?

Comment: If you want to have each function once in the list, you can use `set` instead of `list`. But `set` won't allow you to track the order.

Comment: What exactly are you going to do with such a list, anyway?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the exact use is a bit complicated. Im' making a collectible card game, and cards' behaviour can be changed at runtime. Those behaviors are functions added to lists. The decorator we're talking about should add the default starting behaviors of a card to some lists, and some other cards can later add other behaviors to those lists.

Comment: In fact it seems that what I'm asking is kind of similar to builtin property decorator, isn't it ?

Comment: ... You know you can just add callable attributes to the card objects as you go, and inspect them, yeah?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but I don't think that would do : the same modification can be applied twice on the same card (ie a building can be modified two times to give the player 1 gold at the start of turn, resulting in 2 gold), and the order those behaviors are executed in is important

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't access `self` from the decorator, because the decorator is run at the time the function is defined, and at that time there are no instances of `My_Class` yet.

It's better to put the function list as a class attribute instead of an instance attribute. Then you can pass this list as a parameter to the decorator:

```
def addToList(funcList):
    '''Decorator that adds the function to a given list'''
    def actual_decorator(f):
         funcList.append(f)
         return f
    return actual_decorator

class MyClass(object):
    funcList = []

    @addToList(funcList)
    def some_function(self, name):
        print 'Hello,', name
```

Now you can access `MyClass.funcList` to get the list of decorated functions.

Comment: Does it mean that `funcList` is shared among instances of the class? Because, as I understand, the idea is to track what functions were called for each instance separately.

Comment: @ovgolovin: I read the question as wanting a list of what functions were defined with the decorator (each function appearing exactly once). Now that you mention your interpretation I see that it makes sense as well. I'm not sure which one was meant.

Comment: @CGGJE If you need to have a separate behavior list for each instance, than don't forget to crate a copy of `funcList` in `def __init__`, otherwise all your instance will be sharing the same `funcList`.

Comment: self is passed as the first argument to the instance method, so it can be accessed as args[0], if addToList is written as addToList(*args,**kwargs)

Comment: @TusharAgarwal That's wrong, because `addToList` is not an instance method.

Comment: @interjay its a decorator, acknowledged

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing really special about writing decorators for bound functions (instance methods).  For example, this simple example works fine:

```
def decorator(fn):
    print "I'm decorating!"
    return fn


class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    @decorator
    def my_function(self):
        print "Hi"
```

If you want to use `self` in your decorator, you'll treat your decorator the same as you'd treat any decorator that uses the function's args:

```
def decorator(fn):
    def _decorator(self):
        print "I'm decorating, and here's my list: %s!" % self.list
        return fn(self)
    return _decorator
```

Comment: Will `MyClass` have access to `decorator`? (`decorator` is outside of the class scope).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand 'have access', but you can decorate functions in your class with this decorator, just as long as this decorator is defined before the class is defined (either by importing, or placing the definition in the file, before the class definition).

Comment: By the way, why isn't it possible to use `self.fn()` instead of `fn(self)`? I have an exception if I make this change.

Comment: Well, first off, you have no method named `fn` on the instance of the class (at least in this example).  In this case, fn is just a variable that happens to be a function.  Why would you want to make this change?

Comment: The change is just to understand better what happens in all that class-connected stuff. But I don't completely understand: shouldn't Python call `fn(self,...)` when I use `self.fn(...)`?

Comment: No, because `fn` is a function, if you say `self.fn` you are asking for a function named "fn" on the `self` instance, which is not the case.  If you wanted to call the function like that, you'd need the name of `fn`, which can be found with `fn.__name__`.  This is how it would be used `getattr(self, fn.__name__)()`.  The problem here, is that you'd be calling the decorated function recursively, and you'd get a out-of-stackspace exception (or it would never finish).

Comment: The reason you don't get this when you call `fn` directly, is because it's actually a different function (not yet decorated), so it doesn't end up calling itself.

Comment: "shouldn't Python call fn(self,...) when I use self.fn(...)?" In a sense, yes, but when it does so, it looks up the name `fn` within the class. We want to use the parameter `fn` that was passed to the decorator, instead. That function isn't necessarily named `fn` within the class' context.

Comment: @AdamWagner in your example with _decorator(self), the print statement will be executed at every call to my_function. And I only want my_function to be added once to the list, so I can't do it this way. interjay's solution is more suitable to my precise problem

Comment: @CGGJE, that's fine.  You're question was a bit broad, and @interjay's solution is probably closer to what you were trying to accomplish, I just wanted to show how to have access to `self` in your decorator, which was part of your question.

Comment: But I see no recursive looping when I change to `self.fn()`. What I get is `AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'fn'`.

Comment: @ovgolovin, that's because there is no "fn" on `self`.  The `fn` in `fn(self)` has nothing to do with the `fn` in `self.fn()`.

Comment: @AdamWagner Your answer helped me too, I'm just trying to master those decorators and your explanations were useful. Thank you

Comment: @CGGJE You can use Adam's answer to achieve adding `my_function` once to the list. Just put the statement of adding to the list between `def decorator...` and `def _decorator`. It's what actually interjay did in his code. It was just a bit ambiguous, when you want the function to be added to the list. And here Adam explains how to add  the function to the **bound** list of the instance.

Comment: @AdamWagner Thanks! I seem to have eventually understood the point. Still, don't understand where the recursion comes from. `fn.__name__` doesn't call the `fn` functions. It only gets its name.

Comment: @ovgolovin, that would be a good topic for a new question!  I don't have time to anwer it now, but you'll probably get good answers from other folks around here.

Comment: @ovgolovin you're right, but only if you add my_function to a class-attribute list, since `self` is defined only after def_decorator(self). What I find interesting in Adam Wagner's answer is precisely the use of self.

Comment: @AdamWagner Thanks! You actually answered a lot to give a good insight into the answer to a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your `list` attribute should be a class attribute (and it should be renamed, because `list` is a builtin type). Then you can do something like this:

```
my_methods = []

def my_method(method):
    my_methods.append(method)
    return method


class MyClass(object):

    my_methods = my_methods

    @my_method
    def my_function(self):
       print 'Hi'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this inside your decorator

```py
import inspect
def get_stack(stack_depth=1):
    call_stack = inspect.stack()
    return list(map(lambda frame_info: (frame_info.frame.f_locals.get('self', None), frame_info.function)
        , call_stack[1:stack_depth + 1]))

def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        caller = get_stack(2)[-1]  # depending on implementations, you may need soething other than '2'
        print('\tstack', caller[0], caller[1], '->', func.__name__)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

or just take the first argument as self:

```py
def selfDecorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        self_ = args[0]
        print('\t', self_, func.__name__)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```