# How to access constructor variables in python decorator?

Tags: python, multithreading, class, methods, decorator

I have created a class and declared some variables inside it's constructor.

This class also has some methods.

I have also created a decorator which takes a parameter.

What I want is to use that decorator before those methods and pass one of the variable from the class constructor.

Below is my code:

**Decorator:**

```py
def thread_switch_decorator(argument):
    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            argument.stop()
            result = function(*args, **kwargs)
            argument.start()
            return result

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

**Class and Methods:**

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_thread = initiate_connect()
    
    @thread_switch_decorator(argument=self.my_thread) # <--- Here is the problem
    def home_page(self):
        pass
```

**Error:**

```
@thread_switch_decorator(argument=self.my_thread)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

On the code above where I am using the decorator I can not pass the parameter from the constructor. Which is logical.

My question is, how can I do this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375862/self-in-python-decorators

Comment: this is not posible, you cannot acces an instance attribute via froñ an object that has not been created, the arguments of a decorator are reader the first time the scrip is reader and thus there are no instance attributes. You can on the contrary accec class attributes. In any case what are you trying to achieve in this code?